# Simultaneous mysqli_stmt prepared queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I have following code:

```
<ol>
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("host","login","pass","dbase");
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM table1 WHERE faculty=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("d",$fac);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$name);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<li>$name:<ul>";
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT mac,ip FROM table2 WHERE uid=?");
        $stmt2->bind_param("d",$id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->bind_result($mac,$ip);
        while($stmt2->fetch())
        {
            echo "<li>$mac ($ip)</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
?>
</ol>
```

I get the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. I know that I cannot have multiple queries running at once, but I've read, that I can use `$stmt->store_result()`. The problem is, that it does not help in my case (I tried calling it just after `$stmt->execute()`). How can I get my code working? Is it possible to do it **without** storing the results of first query in an array?

Comment: Why not just do a single query with a join?

Comment: @Steve that's one way to do it, but I wanted to know if there is any easier possibility, since my actual code and the second query are much more complicated and rewriting them to have one long query and a piece of code spliting the results into groups (as in this example) would be a real pain in the neck...

Comment: The easier possibility *is* doing the query properly, rather than trying to get PHP to bend this way. Another way is closing the connection to the database each time you do a query.

Comment: right. So I'm gonna stick to the joined query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single query with a `LEFT JOIN` will work in this case:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`name`, `t2`.`mac`, `t2`.`ip`
FROM `table1` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `t2`
ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`uid`
WHERE `t2`.`uid` = ?
```

This query will return all four columns in one shot provided `id` in table 1 is `uid` in table 2.